# Is it possible to perform a cond_wait if a condition holds true atomically in pthreads?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, pthreads, wait, atomic

I have a code that has a deadlock. I thought about a few solutions of how to solve it and one of them was to do the following atomically:

```
if(!ready)
    pthread_cond_wait(&(cond[0]), &(lock[0]));
```

However, I'm not sure if it is possible to do this atomically in pthreads, since I couldn't find anything in the documentation, perhaps there might be a trick of how to do it. I won't explain the rest of the code, since I don't think it is relevant to answer this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's atomic with respect to modifications of `ready` because the mutex `lock[0]` is held, and must be held around all modifications to `ready` in other threads.

Note that you need to use `while` and not `if`, because the wait may wake up early even if the condition hasn't changed.

Comment: That's true, but I want to avoid having other threads trying to acquire lock[0] just to set the ready variable, since it would mean that would have to wait until this thread releases the lock, which only happens when it gets to the wait.

Comment: You only need to lock it immediately before the test.